# Found suspicious function in Coin Contract code

Tags: contract-development, tokens, etherscan, bsc

I'm new to creating cryptos and doing all the programming of it.

Recently I came across a very suspicious token called `BEAR` that might be a Honeypot scam.
Here's the function I don't understand and has been used only a few times in all the cryptos contracts codes:

```
contract BEAR is TokenERC20 {

  function clearCNDAO() public onlyOwner() {
    address payable _owner = msg.sender;
    _owner.transfer(address(this).balance);
  }
```

Here's the full source code [(link)](https://etherscan.io/address/0x4f1368354afcd6a5cabeffe5db6f1b523fe85b21#code#L1)

I was able to track down multiple different coins using this function and all of them have a lot of signs of being a honeypot scam. Here's an example of that [(link)](https://bscscan.com/address/0x37f12711e6b861a55f447da0cba0261ec66a8868#code#L1)

Could anyone confirm my suspicion or explain what the mentioned function does?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi JackPieCZ! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! That function transfer the ether balance to the owner. Most tokens do not allow ether transfers. That function by itself doesn't seems like a scam but is suspicious. The other suspicious things is the function `transfernewun`.

Comment: @Ismael That's so much for your insight. I really appreciate it. Yeah the transfernewun looks very suspicious as well. Is there a way how can the creator of the token execute those functions at any given time? And if yes, how? Is there something like a command line related to your token where you can execute those commands? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Yes, the owner can send a transaction with the command it will execute. It just need a wallet that can call a contract, like metamask.

Comment: Does it mean something? or is it honeypotscam? Detected 0x8632...9 with 1224.51 TAU Token (TAU)(0.00%) - (contract)
- Contract code : suspicious burn function detected !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a code perspective, the owner is simply able to transfer contract's balance to them at their whim.

But, token contracts which are legitimate generally don't implement ether transfers to owners atleast. Maybe because the contract can use the `mint` function and increase it's supply which can then permit the owner to swap those newly minted tokens on a DEX and then rug pull the users.

Had the ether transfer function did not exist, there would not be this case as the ether transfer would not happen at the owner's whim.